Trouble connecting to WebSocket server due to 401 status code, in Spring Boot
I am trying to learn how to use WebSockets for a project I am working on. Till now I found some code templates that seem to work when I run them. Problem is whenever I test them out in postman or other APIs I keep getting the Unauthorized status code.
From my understanding, I could solve the problem by adding security configurations to the project to allow for all of the endpoints to be seen, but I don't really know how to do that since some codes that I tried regarding it don't work either. Also, this last code is supposed to work without additional configurations as I understood from the tutorial, so what exactly am I doing wrong?
Here are some details regarding my code, I'm not exactly sure that I understand how it works yet so please be patient with me:)
here is my pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>BackEndApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>BackEndApp</name>
    <description>BackEndApp</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>BackEndApp</artifactId>
           <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

the WebSocketConfig class:
package config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.socket.CloseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketHandler;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketMessage;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketSession;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocket;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketHandlerRegistry;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(new WebSocketHandler() {
            @Override
            public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {

            }

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(WebSocketSession session, WebSocketMessage<?> message) throws Exception {

            }

            @Override
            public void handleTransportError(WebSocketSession session, Throwable exception) throws Exception {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus closeStatus) throws Exception {

            }

            @Override
            public boolean supportsPartialMessages() {
                return false;
            }
        }, "/websocket").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }
}

and the WebSocketHandler:
package WebSocketHandler;

import org.springframework.web.socket.TextMessage;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketSession;
import org.springframework.web.socket.handler.TextWebSocketHandler;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class WebSocketHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

    private static Set<WebSocketSession> sessions = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        sessions.add(session);
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) throws Exception {
        for (WebSocketSession webSocketSession : sessions) {
            if (webSocketSession.isOpen()) {
                try {
                    webSocketSession.sendMessage(message);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Please feel free to leave some advice as to what I have to improve in my approach since I am new to this:) thank you in advance!

you have spring-boot-starter-security so all the endpoints by default will require authentication. Either configure security or remove the dependency if not needed - in that case your endpoints will be freely accessible by everyone
